# Add multiple products with one submit button

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, products, controllers

I have in my `view.phtml` some products and one submit button for each product and all works fine. Now i want to submit all products with one button(**submit multiple products**), I tried this [solution](http://www.thienphucvx.com/adding-multiple-products-to-cart-in-magento/) and the problem that I can't get the products params in my controller.

**view.phtml**

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $prod) : ?>
<?php if($prod->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($prod) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $prod->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php if(!$prod->isGrouped()): ?>
            <?php $productId = $prod->getId(); ?>
            <?php $productCartQty = $this->getCartQty($prod); ?>
            <div class="border-new-cart-button">
                <span class="plus qty-add" style="float:right;" onclick="plusQty('qty-<?php echo $productId ?>')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="input-qty-product number-control" title="Qty" value="<?php echo /*$this->getProductDefaultQty() * */ 0 ?>" name="qty" id="qty-<?php echo $productId ?>"/>
                <span class="moins qty-remove" style="float:right;" onclick="minusQty('qty-<?php echo $productId ?>')"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" class="btn add-to-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Valider') ?></span></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
     </form>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

/*My one add button*/
 <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/addmultiple'); ?>" method="post" id="products_addtocart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="multiple_products" id="multiple_products" value="" />
    <button class="btn add-to-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add all products') ?></span></button>
</form>

/*JS PART*/
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#products_addtocart_form").on('submit',function(e){
        var products = {};
        jQuery('input[name="products[]"]').each(function() {
            var productId = jQuery(this).val();
            var productqty = jQuery('input[qtyproduct='+ productId +']').val();
            if(parseInt(productqty)>0){
                products[productId]= productqty;
            }
        });
        jQuery('#multiple_products').val(JSON.stringify(products));
        return;

    });
</script>
```

**Checkout/CartController.php**

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class Compagny_Catalog_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {

    public function addmultipleAction() {
        $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('multiple_products');
        Mage::log($productIds); // I get an empty array
        $productIds = json_decode($productIds,true);
        Mage::log($productIds); // I get also an empty array
         if (!is_array($productIds)) {
             Mage::log('product parameter not found !');
             $this->_goBack();
             return;
         }

         foreach( $productIds as $prodId => $prodQty) {
             try {
                 $prodId = intval($prodId);
                 $qty = intval($prodQty);
                 if($qty>0)continue;
                 $cart = $this->_getCart();
                 $cart->init();
                 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                     ->load($prodId);
                 $eventArgs = array(
                     'product' => $product,
                     'qty' => $qty,
                     'additional_ids' => array(),
                     'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                     'response' => $this->getResponse(),
                 );
                 if(!$product){
                     continue;
                 }

                 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_before_add', $eventArgs);

                 $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);

                 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_after_add', $eventArgs);

                 $cart->save();

                 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product', array('product'=>$product));

                 $message = $this->__('%s was successfully added to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());
                 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
             }
             catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                 if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                 }
                 else {
                     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception $e) {
                 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, $this->__('Can not add item to shopping cart'));
             }
         }
         $this->_goBack();
     }
}
```

Comment: try merging both form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody was able to solve the issue, I debugged the code and I solved the problem, so for those who want to use the solution here is it:

**view.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/addmultiple')?>" method="post" id="products_addtocart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $prod) : ?>
        <div class="product-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $productId ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="productName[]" value="<?php echo $prod->getName() ?>" />
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" class="input-qty-product number-control" title="Qty" value="<?php echo /*$this->getProductDefaultQty() * */ 0 ?>"  id="qty-<?php echo $productId ?>"/>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <button id="one_submit_all_products" class="btn add-to-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Ajouter les produits au panier') ?></span></button>
</form>
```

**app/code/local/Compagny/Catalog/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class Compagny_Catalog_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {

    /**
     * @object add multiple products with one submit button in view.phtml
     */

    public function addmultipleAction() {
        $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productId');
        $productQtys = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
        $productIdQty = (array_combine($productIds,$productQtys));
         if (!is_array($productIds)) {
             Mage::log('product parameter not found !');
             $this->_goBack();
             return;
         }
         foreach($productIdQty as $prod=> $productQtys) {

                 try {
                     $prodId = intval($prod);
                     $qty = intval($productQtys);
                     if($qty<=0)continue;
                     $cart = $this->_getCart();
                     $cart->init();
                     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                         ->load($prodId);
                     $eventArgs = array(
                         'product' => $product,
                         'qty' => $qty,
                         'additional_ids' => array(),
                         'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                         'response' => $this->getResponse(),
                     );
                     if (!$product) {
                         continue;
                     }
                     Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_before_add', $eventArgs);
                     $cart->addProduct($product->getId(), $qty); //the product_id, qty
                     Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_after_add', $eventArgs);
                     $cart->save();
                     Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product', array('product' => $product));
                     $message = $this->__('The product %s has been added to cart.', $product->getName());
                     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
                 } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                     if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                         Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                     } else {
                         Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                     }
                 } catch (Exception $e) {
                     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, $this->__('Can not add item to shopping cart'));
                 }
         }
         $this->_goBack();
     }

}
```